How to check if an intervention helps a continuous variable (angle) stay within normal limits?
I have two different surgical interventions, and they are both used to treat cervical stenosis. One of the predictors of long-term success is the spinal alignment (relative angles of the vertebra).
The mean of both samples is equivalent. Repeated measures ANOVA shows they are also similar in how much the angles changed in a year of follow-up.
However, some patients already had good alignment before the intervention, but their heads dropped to the front in follow-up, while others had bed alignment and were improved by surgery, yet their heads dropped later, but to a lesser degree than before.
However, I'm using preoperative angles and comparing them to the one-year follow-up. Would it be better to use post-operative angles to better alleviate this issue? What would be the best approach for this data set?

You appear to be asking us for a medical opinion concerning what "long-term success" might mean.  This wouldn't be the right forum for that!

Hmm. Maybe I should rephrase that. I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to see if the patients who were in bad alignment were fixed and still were fixed at one-year follow-up, and the same for the patients who already had good alignment and didn't get worse due to surgery. This is easy if I just categorize them into "good" and "bad" alignment groups. But alignment angle and relative distances are continuous data that shouldn't be categorized if possible, no?

What I have done in what I think are similar circumstances is use "distance away from perfect".  That is, some degree of alignment is ideal (I think???) and you then make a measure that is how far away from that alignment a patient is.  But I am not sure this exactly meets your needs.

The issue is there is not really a perfect alignment, but rather patients has an alignment that can be considered normal (within high-low thresholds)
